# Laravel polymorphic relations: how to handle "shared" data

Tags: php, inheritance, laravel, polymorphism

I'm currently working on a content management system in Laravel 4.
The current situation is that a Page class has many Item classes. Plain and simple.
As time passed, the Item class grew in size where we implemented new features or data an Item could store. At this point, an Item can contain information for -containers, plain text, images, navigation, besides "shared" data that every item always has, eg. position, is_visible, etc.

Now my belief is that the current state is unmanagable, so i started thinking of deviding the Item class into multiple "inheriting" classes (as a C# developers background), like this:

Item.php

- id
- position
- isVisible
- isCommentable

Container.php inherits Item.php

- bgColor
- bgImage
- size

Text.php inherits Item.php

- header
- content

(So again, all this from a C# point of view).

Now, since I'm working in Laravel, having the Item class inheriting from Eloquent, I thought the proper solution is to bind Container/Text classes to the Item class by morphMany and morphTo functionallity. The wall I'm hitting is this one: should I make choose to "create" a Text object: how would I ensure that the "base data" in the Item-class gets filled aswell.

When setting up the system, I'm working with migrations to fill the first records.

**Text.php**

```
class Text extends Eloquent {
protected $fillable = [];

public function items()
{
    return $this->morphMany('Item', 'itemable');
}}
```

**Item.php**

```
class Item extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = "items";

    public function page()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Page');
    }


    public function itemable()
    {

        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

I will spare you the table setup migrations, it's the insert that i'm interested in:

```
public function up()
{
    DB::table('containers')->insert(array(
        'bgColor'=>'#ffebcf',
        'bgImage'=>'img/header-jumbotron.png',
        'bgImageRepeat'=>'repeat',
        'bgPosition'=>'left top',
   ));
}
```

When executing this, offcourse, it won't have any information for the initial Item object. But this should be required because without this information, the Container object shouldn't excist at all. Maybe my thinking is a little weird, or I'm missing something that is very very obvious. I'm looking for a neat solution that fits my 'thoughtproces' - can't find it! At this time: the wall has struck. 
Also - I would like some feedback as to my approach. Is this the right thing to do in the first place? Appreciated!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think having multiple classes (with differing fields) of the polymorphic (item) type isn't really the way Laravel's polymorphism works. In a way, you're kinda doing a polymorphic polymorphism, and Laravel only knows about the regular type(!) I think the way to achieve what you want would actually be to model the polymorphic polymorphs as more of a key/value situation so you still have one consistent polymorphic table, but it has multiple 'attributes' as children. So `Page` has many `Item` (and maybe also `NewsItem` has many `Item`) and then `Item` has many `Attribute`.

Comment: Don't think we're on the same page. Im not looking for dynamic polymorphing, which you describe as polymorphic polymorphs? As far is i know, im not doing anything other then the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations), it should be possible to create an (eg.) Container-object that also has the base-class (Item.php) variables (eg. position or isVisible) or?

Comment: Okay but it seemed to me like you wanted to be able to have one type of polymorph on one object and another type of polymorph on a different object. Anyway, if that's not what you want ignore me as I'm talking about something else. It still feels like you're not doing *exactly* what's required from polymorphic relationships though. But I'm not the best person to help here.